# TBB cmake compile trouble

Tags: c++, gcc, tbb

I got tbb lib and compile successful.
like that
g++ test.cpp -ltbb

but using cmake tbb class having undefined reference error..

my cmakelist is very simple.

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

project (Tutorial)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ltbb")

add_executable(Tutorial test.cpp)

i use add_definitions but it's same.

UBUNTU 16.06 LTS / gcc 5.3.1 / CMAKE 3.5.1

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the undefined reference error you received?

Comment: test.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb19task_scheduler_initC2Eim[_ZN3tbb19task_scheduler_initC5Eim]+0x40): undefined reference to `tbb::task_scheduler_init::initialize(int, unsigned long)'